# Как можно разместить png картинку за пределами окна tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, tkinter, pyqt

Как можно было бы сделать например новогоднюю шляпу за пределами окна *tkinter* вот так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если что это фотошоп

Comment: Насчет tk не подскажу, но на PyQt такое можно сделать меньше чем за 10 строк: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5a780831079c69cd2351a2249d6c8397c6f27a57/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/QWidget_setMask__frameless_window/main.py

Answer (score 2):

Прежде чем запустить мой пример, убедитесь, что вы установили `PyQt5`

```
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

`PyQt` — реализация фреймворка `Qt` для языка `Python`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

 
class Demo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("NY2.png").scaled(
            150, 150, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.FastTransformation)

        pal = self.palette()
        pal.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Normal, QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QBrush(pixmap))
        pal.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QBrush(pixmap))
        self.setPalette(pal)
        self.setMask(pixmap.mask())
        self.offset = None
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            self.offset = event.pos()
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and self.offset is not None:
            self.move(self.pos() - self.offset + event.pos())
            return True
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            self.offset = None
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

        
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Demo()
    w.resize(150, 150)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]